# What type of "ladder" are these plants on?

Tags: tools

What type of "ladder" are these plants on?

[image: image 1]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it, apart from its being deeply unattractive, it seems to me to be something that's been pressed into service for a purpose other than that for which it was originally intended. Perhaps its been cobbled together by the owner in a different form, or it was conveniently structured to just stick some (now slowly rotting) wood shelves onto it.

Most 'sold for purpose' plant 'ladders' or stands of this kind have black or green metalwork, usually with a metal grid shelf for the plants to allow water to drain.